# Add language pack to Windows IoT Core

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

Is it possible to add a language pack to Windows IoT Core? I am using the SpeechRecognizer API and would like to add other languages. From what I can see in code, only en-US is an available language with the default installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > Time & language > Region & language and [install your favorite language(here I use French) on your windows 10 PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/60f32ff8-8697-4452-af7d-647439c38433/how-to-add-an-input-language-to-your-pc). After the installation is complete, you need to select France listed in Languages of Settings > Time & language > Region & language and click the Options. You will see something like this:

[image]

Make sure you click on the Download button of the Speech option. After that you have "fr-FR" folder in your PC we will use in step 2 & 3.

2. Copy the ‘fr-FR’ folder from C:\Windows\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS (of the PC) and paste it to Windows\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS of the Windows IoT device(here I use Raspberry Pi 3). You can [access the files on your device using Windows file sharing](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/windowsfilesharing).
3. Second copy is a little more complex because the Common directory that we want to access is protected. First, you copy the ‘fr-FR’ folder from C:\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common (of the PC) and paste it to Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore of the Windows IoT device. Then, we need to use [PowerShell](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/powershell) to connect the IoT device and navigate to Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore, run this command: `mv .\fr-FR\ .\Common\` will move the ‘fr-FR’ folder into Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common directory.

To test if it works, use this piece of code:

```
        foreach (var languages in SpeechRecognizer.SupportedTopicLanguages)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DisplayName: {languages.DisplayName} LanguageTag: {languages.LanguageTag}");
        }
```

You will see the following printed lines in Output window of Visual Studio:

```
DisplayName: English (United States) LanguageTag: en-US
DisplayName: French (France) LanguageTag: fr-FR
```

Initial post is here: https://blog.paulfasola.fr/en/add-voices-windows-10-iot-core-tts/